# How can pdf be attached to mails in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, pdf

I am trying to send a mail to a user but also want to attach a file to the mail. I am using the pdf package barryvdh/laravel-dompdf but I keep getting this error

> Call to a member function attachData() on null at /app_path/app/Nova/Actions/SendAccountStatement.php:86)

This is my code

```
$data = [...];

$pdf = PDF::loadView('account-statement', $data);

// send account statement notification
Mail::to($model->email)
  ->bcc('another@mail.com')
  ->send(new StatementOfAccount($model)
  ->attachData($pdf->output(), "Account_Statement.pdf", ['mime' => 'application/pdf']);
```

The line throwing the error is `->attachData($pdf->output(), "Account_Statement.pdf", ['mime' => 'application/pdf'])`

So from the error, I seem to missing something. What is the right way to attach a pdf file to the email?

Answer (score -1):

> app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

```
use App\Mail\CheckUser;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PDF;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {   
       return view('welcome');
    }

    public function daily_report(Request $request)
    {
       $start_date = Carbon::parse($request->start_date)
                             ->toDateTimeString();

       $end_date = Carbon::parse($request->end_date)
                             ->toDateTimeString();

       $data['users'] = User::whereBetween('created_at',[$start_date,$end_date])->get();
       
       $data['start_date'] = Carbon::parse($request->start_date)
                             ->toDayDateTimeString();
       $data['end_date'] = Carbon::parse($request->end_date)
                             ->toDayDateTimeString();
       
       $count = User::whereBetween('created_at',[$start_date,$end_date])->count();

       if( $count < 1 ) {
        session()->flash('message','There is no user between those date!');
        return redirect()->back();
       }

       $pdf = PDF::loadView('test', $data, [
                   'format' => 'A4'
              ]);

        \Mail::send('test', $data, function($message) use ($pdf){
            $message->from('info@test.com*');
            $message->to('mail@codechief.org');
            $message->subject('Date wise user report');
            $message->attachData($pdf->output(),'document.pdf');
        });

       $pdf->SetProtection(['copy', 'print'], '', 'pass');
       return $pdf->stream('document.pdf'); 

    }
}
```

> One is for form and the other is our generated pdf file. So create it.
>
> ```
> resources/views/welcome.blade.php
> ```

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
    @push('style')
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    @endpush
    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
    
              @if(session()->has('message'))
                <p class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-sm custom_message text-left" style="margin-top: 10px;">{{ session()->get('message') }}</p>
              @endif
    
              <legend>Search date wise user</legend>
    
              <form action="{{ route('report') }}" method="get">
                
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Start Date</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="start_date">
                </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">End Date</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="end_date">
                </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top: 24px;">
                   <div class="form-group">
                     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Tried doing it this way but ended up with this error `fopen(/app_path/storage/fonts//nunito-sans-600-italic_ade62d68a3797e291e5838e264052318.ufm): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: make sure you have directory